# React Flow possible null value with document.body.classList.add

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I have a react component where I change the html body class. The class is being added in componentDidMount and removed in componentWillUnmount. I am using Flow for type checking. When I run Flow I get the following error:

```
src/modules/homepage/HomePage.js:27
 27:         document.body.classList.remove('homepage')
                           ^^^^^^^^^ property `classList`. Property cannot be accessed on possibly null value
 27:         document.body.classList.remove('homepage')
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ null
```

Can anyone suggest how to suppress this error or what would be the recommended approach?

Thank you

Answer (score 10):

This error is exactly what it sounds like. Property `classList` cannot be accessed on possibly null value. (`document.body`)

`document.body` is not defined until the [document.readyState is interactive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState). You can similarly wait for the `domcontentready` or `load` events, but you're probably already doing that since you're rendering React components.

In practice, flow is kind of annoying here because in a browser environment once `document.body` is defined, it stays defined.

Here are some easy solutions:

You can use an `invariant` function:
    invariant(document.body); // throw an error if document.body does not exist yet
    document.body.classList.remove('homepage');

Or put the statement in an if block:

```
if (document.body) {
    document.body.classList.remove('homepage') 
}
```

Comment: Thanks this really help..also I came across an annotation // $flowfixme with a regex in config to just ignore the check ..but your suggestion is lot cleaner :)

Comment: unfortunately flow just ignores the conditional check so I ended up with declare var document: Object; on top of the file

Comment: It's not clear how to declare invariant function, any reference to docs or example is welcome.

Comment: @ilyaigpetrov
`const invariant = <T>(x: ?T): T => { 
  if (!x) { throw new Error() }
  return x
}`

Comment: You can also use `type casting` like this: `const body = ((document.body:any):HTMLBodyElement)`

Answer (score 1):

Used:

```
document.body !== null && document.body.classList.remove('homepage');
```

seemed to fix the flow error for me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
`document.body?.classList.remove('homepage')`